# Python APSCheduler Exception management

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, apscheduler

I am using the module `APScheduler` in a script, I use a `BlockingScheduler`. I have some periodic job. If this job `raise` an `Exception`, whatever I `expect` it in a `try` or let it propagates, my thread does not return. Then I reach the `max_instance` and no more job are executed.

How should I manage `Execptions` in threads when using `BlockingScheduler`?

Here my MWE that illustrates my problem:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
import threading

class x:

    def __init__(self):
        self._lock = threading.Lock()

    def __enter__(self):
        print("ENTER")
        self._lock.acquire()
        print("LOCK")
        raise Exception("ERROR")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print("EXIT")
        self._lock.release()
        print("UNLOCK")

a = x()

def test():
    print("TEST")
    with a:
        print("WITH")

pollingScheduler = BlockingScheduler()
pollingScheduler.add_job(test, 'interval', seconds=1, max_instances=1)
pollingScheduler.start()
```

I expected that `__exit__()` method must be called when raising a Exception, even if it is `__enter__()` that raise it. After testes, I see that `__exit__()` is not called is such scenario. Therefore it leads to a deadlock and the thread stucks.

How should I solve this?
It looks like `__enter__()` must not raise Exception. Is it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `__exit__` is only called if `__enter__` completes successfully. Since you are raising the exception in `__enter__`, the lock is left in an acquired state so the subsequent run of the job will hang when trying to acquire the lock. If you expect an exception in `__enter__`, wrap it in a `try...except` block that will release the lock if an exception is raised.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out when building the MWE. Thank you for answering. I was not aware of this with statement behaviour.

Comment: I have resolved it this way, I embed my sensitive code into a `try...except` block and then I call `__exit__` if something went wrong in `__enter__` and I reraise `exception` to let them propagate. Is that a good practice?

Comment: Calling `__exit__` from `__enter__`? I wouldn't do that.

Comment: Could you be more explicit. I call `__exit__` only if I have a error that I cannot recover from. Therefore I must release resource that I have already opened and this is the purpose of `__exit__`. Isn't that right.

Comment: Or maybe should I create some others functions that I call in `__enter__` and `__exit__`. Anyway, could you please explain why it is a good practice if `__exit__` is not called when `__enter__` craches.